# How to control a torrent file to be downloaded item by item

Tags: transmission

Look at this img:
[image]

Generally, Transmission tries to download all of items which are defined in a torrent file, concurrently. For example, if we have 10 item in a torrent file, after 1 hour, they can be in a range of 15% - 50% of progress (depending to the rate of download).

Is it possible to force Transmission to download items one by one: alphabetically or by sizes, etc.
I know I can check/uncheck items manually as you see in the above image, but I'm asking for a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Maybe you can try deluge that allows you to prioritize files and there's even a plugin that allows you to download sequentially all pieces (by prioritization)

Comment: @Braiam, I need to run the client on GDM, without login and Transmission-Daemon can do it while graphical torrent clients such as deluge need login to Desktop!

Comment: Are you sure? I can have `deluged` as daemon running on boot without even login.

Comment: Wow, `Deluge` vs `Deluged`; so I'll try it in `Cron`.

Comment: Cron? Why cron? Just set it up to start at the system startup.

Comment: @Braiam, Then, will it be run without login to the desktop? is '_system startup_' acting from _GDM/lightDM_ step? `Cron` defines a job which can be run in any case.

Comment: `deluged` is a daemon, it doesn't need login because it can run as a system service. By the way, downloading copyrighted material (as it seems from your screenshot) is illegal almost everywhere, and the information provided here is not meant to endorse such activities. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2):

libtransmission has a python API, so you could script anything you want... but no, that feature is not baked in.

Here's a working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import transmissionrpc

tc = transmissionrpc.Client('localhost', port=(9091))

torrents = tc.get_torrents()
for torrent in torrents:
  if torrent.status == 'downloading':
    low = []
    torrent_files = torrent.files()
    for item in torrent_files:
      low.append(item)
    high = []
    for item in sorted(torrent_files, key=lambda x: torrent_files[x]['name']):
      if torrent_files[item]['size'] - torrent_files[item]['completed'] > 0:
        high.append(item)
        break
    try:
      low.pop(low.index(high[0]))
    except:
      pass
    tc.change(torrent.id, priority_high=high, priority_low=low)
```

I put together a desktop widget to do this for me [here](https://github.com/aking1012/torrentWidget).

Comment: Is this script just using port 9091?

Comment: Yes.  It's the default transmission-rpc port that only accepts connections from 127.0.0.1 if enabled without auth and no trusted hosts are specified.